# How to get Stereo stream in PCM

Tags: javascript, audio, socket.io, pcm

I am trying to stream audio using SocketIO from client to server. Here is the code in javascript i am using for streaming.

```
recorder.onaudioprocess = function(e){
    if(!recording) return;
    console.log ('recording');
    var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    window.Stream.write(convertoFloat32ToInt16(left));
  }
```

Here i am just streaming Left channel. But the audio has 2 channels(Stereo). Result of that i am receiving bad quality audio at server side. Is there any way i can get both channels to stream.

Thank you in advance.